# PHP Mysqli query retrieves more values than it should

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, while-loop

this is my first post here, im currently learning php at free times, im trying to develop an aplication and i got myself with an error that i cant find solution. At the code i posted, when a condition reaches this part:

```
elseif ($result2['ODT'] == '0'){
                            $query3 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT po.texto, po.nextp FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and po.id != '10' and po.id != '7' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
                            $row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3);
                            echo '<option value="'.$row1['nextp'].'">'.$row1['texto'].'</option>';}
```

It gives me 2 values, 2 select options, but if i run it directly on phpmyadmin, it retrieves me only 1 row. What am i doing wrong there?
The correct is the 1 row, and not 2, i presume it must be something about the while. Thanks in advance

```
function Select1() {
    header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1",true);

    include 'dbconfig.php';

    $query = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT p.textop, p.np, p.ap, po.texto, po.nextp, u.uap FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($row_cnt > 0){
                while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $query1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT uap FROM usergame WHERE userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'");
                    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
                    if(($result['uap'] !== '230')and($result['uap'] !== '20')){
                    echo "<option value='".$row['nextp']."'>".$row['texto']."</option>";}

                    elseif(($result['uap'] == '230')or($result['uap'] == '20')){
                    $query2 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT ODT FROM userencantos WHERE userEID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'");
                    $result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
                        if ($result2['ODT'] > '0'){echo '<option value="'.$row['nextp'].'">'.$row['texto'].'</option>';}
                        elseif ($result2['ODT'] == '0'){
                            $query3 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT po.texto, po.nextp FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and po.id != '10' and po.id != '7' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
                            $row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3);
                            echo '<option value="'.$row1['nextp'].'">'.$row1['texto'].'</option>';}
                        }
                }
            }else{
                echo '<option value="">Nada foi encontrado na BD</option>';
            }
};
```

Comment: Please reformat you question.

Comment: raveenanigan reformatted, thx mate... sorry for bad format on the question

Comment: what is the value of ` $row_cnt` ??

Comment: value of $row_cnt is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys, but i solved it myself :) i changed the code and it works perfectly now.

```
function Select1() {
header("Content-Type: text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1",true);

include 'dbconfig.php';

$query = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT uap FROM usergame WHERE userGID     = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

if(($result['uap'] !== '230')and($result['uap'] !== '20')){
$query1 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT p.textop, p.np, p.ap, po.texto, po.nextp, u.uap FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['nextp']."'>".$row['texto']."</option>";}
}

elseif(($result['uap'] == '230')or($result['uap'] == '20')){
$query2 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT ODT FROM userencantos WHERE userEID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'");
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    if ($result2['ODT'] > '0'){
        $query3 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT p.textop, p.np, p.ap, po.texto, po.nextp, u.uap FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
        $row_cnt1 = mysqli_num_rows($query3);
            while($row1 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3)){
                echo "<option value='".$row1['nextp']."'>".$row1['texto']."</option>";}
        }
    elseif ($result2['ODT'] == '0'){
        $query4 = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT po.texto, po.nextp FROM paginas p, pagsop po, usergame u WHERE u.userGID = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."' and po.id != '10' and po.id != '7' and p.np=u.uap and po.np = p.np");
        $row_cnt2 = mysqli_num_rows($query4);
            while($row2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4)){
                echo "<option value='".$row2['nextp']."'>".$row2['texto']."</option>";}
        }
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change this part from "or" to "and" ?

```
elseif(($result['uap'] == '230')or($result['uap'] == '20')){
```

to

```
elseif(($result['uap'] == '230')and($result['uap'] == '20')){
```

Comment: yes, but with an and there i got 2 empty selects, but once again, 2 selects